# Use jQuery to get descendants of an element that are not children of a container with a certain CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a situation in which i need to select all descendants of a certain element, but **exclude** those that are children of a container that equals the CSS class of the container i run my selector on.

Pretty complicated description.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="element"></div>
           <div class="element"></div>
           <div class="element"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Running a jQuery .find('.element') on the outermost DIV will get me all the DIVs, even the ones inside the second container. That is what i try to avoid.

Is there a quick and simple jQuery selector solution for this case?

Comment: Can you point to me which elements you want selected?

Comment: In this case, the 4 DIVs at level 1 with the class "element"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think what you want to use is the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector. Like this..

```
$(".container").not(".container .container")
```

Alternately, you could use the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selector, to get the children from one level deep. Which would exlclude the nested divs.

To be a little more explicit, I think you'll want to use the not selector after you use the 'find'. Like this:

```
$(".container").find(".element").not($(".container .container .element"))
```

You can pass a function to not, so you could have that function look at the parents of each element match to see if it is nested inside of an element with the same class.

http://jsfiddle.net/QXfs2/6/

```
removeIfNested = function(index) {
    // this is the corrent DOM element
    var $this = $(this),
        return_value = false;

    $.each($this.attr('class').split(/\s+/), function(index) {
        if ($this.parents("." + this).length > 0) {
            return_value = default_value || true;
        }
    });

    return return_value;
}


$(".container").find(".element").not(removeIfNested);
```

If you could add a class to the nested container, that would be ideal, then it's just:

```
$(".container").find(".element").not($(".nested .element"))
```

Assuming you added the class "nested", to your inner container div.

Comment: That's very good to know! In my particular case children() was more fitting though. But thanks a lot for bringing my attention to not(). In any case children() did the job. Until i come up with a case where multiple levels are to be supported.

Comment: I found that i had cases where the DIVs are nested within the containers again, which is why i had to dump children(). Using not() seems like a good idea, but the problem is: what selector to use with not() to match the parent container (not the children directly) ?

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I tried applying it but failed in doing so. I found that it might be easier if i just applied an additional CSS class to all descendant containers, so that i could just exclude them easily. But now i don't seem to be finding out what selector to use in order to select all .container DIVs by using .find() and to exclude all elements that are children of an element with a specific css class. - you were faster. Let me try to apply your latest solution.

Comment: This is it. It worked once i applied your final suggestion and added a > between the parent and the child class names within the not() statement. .not($('.canHaveChildren > .element')) - Thank you! You saved my day.

Comment: Applying the .not($(".nested .element")) after the find syntax helped resolve my need to filter after a find all: $(".container").find("*").not($(".element"))

Comment: Thank you so much. Helps me make all table Bootstrap responsive.         $(function() {
            $('table').not('div.table-responsive table').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"></div>');
        });

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example this would work -

```
$("body > div.container > .element")
```

That will only get the top level element divs. If your element collection was in a different structure you could substitue `body` with the collection's container id.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/QAP37/

Comment: I can't apply this solution as even though the example described above is simplified, the actual situation is a bit more complicated. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector like this:

```
find('*:not(.container .container *)')
```

Comment: From : https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/ ....

**Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.** Just so you know...

Answer (score 0):

I found the following slightly more succinct and general than the selected answer.  It works with arbitrarily deeply nested trees:

```
function getNonNestedElements(container, elementSelector, containerSelector) {
  return container.find(elementSelector).not(function(index) {
    var nearest = $(this).closest(containerSelector);
    return nearest[0] !== container[0];
  });
}
```

where:

- `container` is the jQuery object for the root "container" div
- `elementSelector` is the jQuery selector for the element, `.element` in this case
- `containerSelector` is the jQuery selector for the container, `.container` in this case

So this finds all the elements beneath the initial container, then for each element checks to see if its nearest container is the initial container or some other nested container.  If its nearest container is a nested container, it throws it out, so you are just left with descendants which are not inside another container.

Very handy for things like repeating multi-element, nested form fields.