# Attach event handler to all elements except one and its descendants

Tags: jquery, html

Seemingly simple problem: I'm working on a Chrome extension that has a help "window" – actually a `div` – that is shown upon a menu action. Now I want that `div`to be hidden again when the user clicks outside of the `div`. Thus any click on the `div`or its descendant elements should be ignored and all others should trigger hiding of the `div`. This is the only solution I have found that works, but it is ever so inelegant and circumstantial (**later edit**: this code prevents clicking on other elements from having effect, so it is also dysfunctional in addition to being clumsy).

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var flag = 0;//controls whether hiding is allowed

        $("#div1").click(function(){//clicks on div1 should be ignored
          flag = 1;//prevent hiding by third function
        });

        $("#div1").find("*").click(function(){//clicks on descendants of div1 should be ignored 
          flag = 1;//prevent hiding by third function
        });

        $("*").click(function(){//captures all clicks
          if(flag == 1){flag = 0;}//reset flag for next event
          else {$("#div1").hide();}//if allowed, hide
        return false;
        });        
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>    

    <div id="div1" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
      <p>This is a div. It should go away when you click outside of it.</p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="div2" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
      <p>This is another div. <span>If you click on it, or anywhere else outside of the div above, that div should go away.</span></p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm sure there are better solutions. I have looked at previous posts ["Select all elements that are not descendant of a certain class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523954/jquery-select-all-elements-that-are-not-descendant-of-a-certain-class) and ["Use jQuery to get descendants of an element that are not children of a container with a certain CSS class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233604/use-jquery-to-get-descendants-of-an-element-that-are-not-children-of-a-container), but I can't make them work in this context.

Comment: If the code works as it is, and you can show a working example, and you are asking if there is a way to make it better, then this is off topic for Stack Overflow, and you should consider posting the question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you can set a class to the descendant you want to ignore and then set an if : `if($(this).hasClass('yourClass'))`

Comment: event delegation would be so much better than all those click handlers being added.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: @epascarello: Thanks for the reference. the `closest` selector did the trick: `if($(this).closest("#div1").length == 0){$("#div1").hide();}`
[http://api.jquery.com/closest/]

Comment: Good work. Be sure to provide and accept an answer or close your question so it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to work eventually; the code above did produce some unexpected results by preventing subsequent clicks, so I think it's OK to keep the question on StackOverflow.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").click(function(){
    if($(this).closest("#div1").length == 0) {
      if($("div#div1").css("display") != "none"){
        $("div#div1").hide();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
   });
 });
```